# Отправка почты в codeigniter 2.1.0 используя ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

недавно возникла задача сделать форму отправки заявок с сайта который написан на фреймворке codeigniter 2.1.0, я в нем никогда не работал, в своей работе использовал только смс wordpress или статичные html сайты. В процессе моей работы у меня всегда под рукой был рабочий шаблон кода php обработчика который сейчас работает на статических html сайтах, ниже я прикреплю примеры.

Но проблема в том что на codeigniter этот код отказывается работать. В классических случаях я кидаю в корень сайт файл mail.php и все работает. Этот файл подключаю в js.

Также хочу добавить что js код у меня срабатывает корректно но заявки на почту не приходят. Но если создать обычный html документ то все работает корректно. Не работает именно в codeigniter

```js
//E-mail Ajax Send
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php", //Change
    data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    alert("Спасибо за заявку!");
  });
});
return false;
});
```

```html
<form>

  <input type="text" name="Імя" required/>
  <input type="email" name="Email" />
  <input type="tel" name="Телефон" required/>
  <input type="text" name="Адресс" />
  <textarea name="Сообщение"></textarea>

  <section class="center-text buttons-container">
    <input type="reset" class="reset-button" value="Сбросить" />
    <input type="submit" class="accept-button" value="Отправить" />
  </section>
</form>

Этот код php ниже лежит отдельно в корне сайта и подписан как mail.php

<?php

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

//Script Foreach
$c = true;
if ( $method === 'POST' ) {

 $project_name = "Имя сайта";
 $admin_email  = "mail@gmail.com";
 $form_subject = "Заявка c сайта";

 foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
  if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
   $message .= "
   " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
    <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
    <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
   </tr>
   ";
  }
 }
} else if ( $method === 'GET' ) {

 $project_name = "Имя сайта";
 $admin_email  = "mail@gmail.com";
 $form_subject = "Заявка с сайта";

 foreach ( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
  if ( $value != "" && $key != "project_name" && $key != "admin_email" && $key != "form_subject" ) {
   $message .= "
   " . ( ($c = !$c) ? '<tr>':'<tr style="background-color: #f8f8f8;">' ) . "
    <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'><b>$key</b></td>
    <td style='padding: 10px; border: #e9e9e9 1px solid;'>$value</td>
   </tr>
   ";
  }
 }
}

$message = "<table style='width: 100%;'>$message</table>";

function adopt($text) {
 return '=?UTF-8?B?'.Base64_encode($text).'?=';
}

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL .
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL .
'From: '.adopt($project_name).' <'.$admin_email.'>' . PHP_EOL .
'Reply-To: '.$admin_email.'' . PHP_EOL;

mail($admin_email, adopt($form_subject), $message, $headers );
```

Comment: А сервер корректно настроен для отправки писем с помощью функции `mail()`? Есть большая вероятность того, что письмо просто не дошло до получателя, или лежит в папке спам.

Comment: Проблема нашлась в том что у меня mail.php находится в корне папки сайта и в .htaccess стоят редиректы, которые блокируют доступ к .php файлу

Answer (score 1):

Решил, в папке controllers создал php файл с таким кодом и внутри его код обработчика и в js ссылка на него таким видом

```js
//E-mail Ajax Send
$("form").submit(function() { //Change
  var th = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/mail/send/", //Change
    data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    alert("Спасибо за заявку!");
  });
});
return false;
});
```

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Mail extends MY_Public {

 public function send()
 {
    //Здесь код обработчика  
  }
}
```

Comment: На здоровье(помог автору в телегремме, где он скидывал эту ссылку в чатик)

Comment: Спасибо) Мир не без добрых людей)